# In Python, importing twice with class instantiation?

Tags: python

In `models.py` I have:

```
...
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Document):
...
```

In my app both `serve.py` and `models.py` call:

```
from models import User
```

Is that double import going to instantiate the db twice and potentially cause a problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is that double import going to instantiate the db twice and potentially cause a problem?

No it will not. Once a module is imported it remains available regardless of any further imports via the `import` statement.

The module is stored in `sys.modules` once imported.

If you want to **reload the module** you have to use `reload(module)`.

**Example:** `bar.py`

```
xs = [1, 2, 3]
```

**Importing twice:**

```
>>> from bar import xs
>>> id(xs)
140211778767256
>>> import bar
>>> id(bar.xs)
140211778767256
```

Notice that the **identities** are identical?

**Caching:**

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules["bar"] is bar
True
```

Comment: A module can be imported twice if you import it with different paths. Say your `sys.path = ['/a/b', '/a']` and you do `import c; from b import c`.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won’t. Imports are cached in Python, so importing the same module again will not cause it to be executed again.

You can easily confirm that btw. if you just put a print into the module you are importing. If you see the output multiple times, you would be executing the module multiple times. But that simply doesn’t happen.